# Additional method that compares two objects

Tags: java

I'd like to ask you if it's a good approach to have additional method in entity class that compares two objects?

In my entity I have equals and hashcode

`@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = "uuid")`

This is legacy code. I need some other equals method to compare objects by all fields like Street, country itp. because uuid fields is generated only before saving object in database but I need to compare my objects before persisting them so I wonder if it's a good approach to have additional method in entity class like:

```
public boolean isEqualTo(Object o) {
//comparison with all relevant String fields
}
```

or maybe such a method in my service class where this method `isEqualTo` is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with this. There's even precedent: for example, the `String` class has `equalsIgnoreCase` and `contentEquals`. So if you have a class such that two instances could be "equal" in more than one way, just create the methods that you need.